# Python code timings using numba

Tags: python, numba

I am trying to do some timing comparisons using numba.

What I don't understand in the following `mwe.py` is why I get different results

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
from numba import autojit
import time


def timethis(method):
    '''decorator for timing function calls'''
    def timed(*args, **kwargs):
        ts = time.time()
        result = method(*args, **kwargs)
        te = time.time()
        print('{!r} {:f} s'.format(method.__name__, te - ts))
        return result
    return timed


def pairwise_pure(x):
    '''sample function, compute pairwise distancee, see: jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/06/15/numba-vs-cython-take-2/'''
    M, N = x.shape
    D = np.empty((M, M), dtype=np.float)
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(M):
            d = 0.
            for k in range(N):
                tmp = x[i, k] - x[j, k]
                d += tmp * tmp
            D[i, j] = np.sqrt(d)
    return D

# first version
@timethis
@autojit
def pairwise_numba(args):
    return pairwise_pure(args)

# second version
@timethis
def pairwise_numba_alt(args):
    return autojit(pairwise_pure)(args)

x = np.random.random((1e3, 10))

pairwise_numba(x)
pairwise_numba_alt(x)
```

Evaluating `python3 mwe.py` gives this output:

```
'pairwise_numba' 5.971631 s
'pairwise_numba_alt' 0.191500 s
```

In the first version, I decorate the method using timethis to calculate the timings, and with autojit to speed up the code , whereas in the second one  I decorate the function with timethis, and call autojit(...) afterwards.

Does someone have an explanation ?

Comment: I do not know numba, but from decorator point of view the two examples are not equal, in the first you have timethis(autojit(pairwise_numba)) while in the second timethis(pairwise_numba_alt)

Comment: It looks like in the first version, you're just autojitting the wrapper. Maybe it'll delegate to the function it wraps really quickly, but the function it wraps isn't getting jitted.

Comment: @user2357112, yes I think you have the correct analysis, in the first version it looks like  autojit is applied somehow to the wrapper not the function inside, thus resulting in no optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the [documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jit.html#calling-and-inlining-other-functions) explicitly states that for optimization each call to other functions "inside" a decorated function should be decorated as well or it isn't optimized.

For many functions like `numpy` functions that isn't necessary since they are highly optimized but for native python functions it is.